# How do I Convert from LayerDescription.SelectionFeatures to GraphicsLayer?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, .net, development

How do I convert (in a clear and concise way) from

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ArcGISServer.LayerDescription.SelectionFeatures
```

to

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Display.Graphics.GraphicsLayer
```

I want the selected features and the attributes.

*side note:
I got the the selection features via FIDSet returned from a SOAP based MapServerProxy.QueryFeatureIDs query using a buffer geometry to pull intersecting features.*

Comment: Do you want to create a layer from the selected features or just display them on the map?

Comment: I will add the selected features to an existing feature class as well as display on the map.